# VBA/Excel: display alt of a picture on hover

Tags: excel, vba, hover

I have a picture on excel with assigned "alt" text. Is there a way to show that text on mouse hover?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlink, then screen tip should do it.

Comment: I have an assigned macro so I cannot set a link otherwise I loose the macro